# When to add random effects into the model

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, stata, random-effects-model

I'm currently trying to model the number of deaths for each region and gender, for some years. See the data [here](https://pastebin.com/0W6ga4yd). I've explored the data, and the distribution of the number of deaths is similar across years. The distribution between the number of deaths and gender and between the number of deaths and regions seem to vary according to the age. Although similar, some regions have slighty moved distributions regarding to other regions. And as expected, the distribution of the number of deaths for females is a bit moved to the right comparing to males due to higher life expectancy. In that sense, I thought about adding an interaction between region and age and an interaction between gender and age.

This is the model I'm using:

```
xi: meglm Deaths Age cal_year i.Region*Age i.Gender*Age, family(nbinomial) link(log) exposure(Pop) vce(cluster Region)
```

However, now I'm thinking whether I should add random effects instead. I may have spent too much time on this that I'm not able to think clearly.

I've thought about adding an random effect for Gender or Region but I get an error `initial values not feasible r(1400);`. I also thought about adding `Age:Region`or `Age:Gender` considering age as the id but I don't think that makes sense. I'm just trying to get some discussion and feedback as I don't have anyone else to discuss and I think I'm starting to do some weird things :)

Thank you!

Comment: I would have thought you needed a random intercept for Region as results within region seem from your description to be correlated. I would not do the same for sex as it only has two levels. The fitting problems would get more response I suspect on Statalist.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried `xi: meglm Deaths Age cal_year i.Gender*Age, family(nbinomial) link(log) exposure(Pop), || Region:` but I received the same error. Should I delete this question and ask in statalist? To avoid duplication?

Comment: Try a simpler model first without interactions. Your question is on-topic here as it is a statistical issues (when should I use a random effect ...) so I see no particular reason to delete it as your Statalist question will be different - why do I get  r(1400)? I do not use Stata so I have zero idea.

Comment: Thank you! None of the models are great (perhaps why I keep thinking of ways to improve) but the fit of the model with interactions is closer to the observed values than the model without interactions.